# UISwitch to switch between displayed views

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

Can I use UISwitch to choose between 2 viewcontrollers to have displayed when app launches?

If I want page 1 UISwitch off
If I want page 2 UISwitch on

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can segue from one view controller to another view controller using UISwitch.
1. First Design your main.storyboard as follow.
[image: main.sotryboard]

2. Then create two UIViewController class file and assign the class file for this UIViewControllers on main.storyboard.[image]
3. Then create the action outlet for the UISwitch in each UIViewController.
4. Then establish the Segue connection from First ViewController to Second ViewController and give the identifier name for your reference.[image]
5. Then for the switch action outlet on each ViewController give the following Swift 3 code. 
   FirstViewController.swift:

   ```
   import UIKit
   class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
     }
     @IBAction func Switch1(_ sender: UISwitch) {
       if sender.isOn == true {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecond", sender: nil)
       } 
     }
   }
   ```

   SecondViewController.swift:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

     }
     @IBAction func Switch2(_ sender: UISwitch) {
       if sender.isOn == false {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFirst", sender: nil)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Another Way:

In another way, you can switch from one view controller to another using UISwitch by presenting the view controller as a popup in the view that is present on the third view controller view. In that case no need to use two UISwitch on two View Controller.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give this a try